# Collision detection not working for canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to make a game but there are obstacles. I have a (ball) player and a square (obstacle) and I can't figure out how to make a collision detection thing to work. Here's my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Ball Race</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
      <script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawRect = function (x, y) {
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
}

var Object = function () {
this.x = width / 4;
this.y = height / 4;
}
// The Ball constructor
var Ball = function () {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 5;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
};

// Update the ball's position based on its speed
Ball.prototype.move = function () {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 11) {
    this.x = 11;
  } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
    this.x = width - 11;
  } else if (this.y < 11) {
    this.y = 11;
  } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
    this.y = height - 11;
  }
};

// Draw the ball at its current position
Ball.prototype.draw = function () {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true);
};

Object.prototype.draw = function () {
    drawRect(this.x, this.y)
}

//collision types



Object.prototype.checkCollision = function () {
var col1 = this.x == ball.x && this.y == ball.y;
var col2 = this.x + 1 == ball.x && this.y == ball.y;
var col3 = this.x + 2 == ball.x && this.y == ball.y;
var col4 = this.x + 3 == ball.x && this.y == ball.y;
if (col1 || col2 || col3 || col4) {
alert("COLLISION!");
}
}
// Set the ball's direction based on a string
Ball.prototype.setDirection = function (direction) {
  if (direction === "up") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = -5;
  } else if (direction === "down") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 5;
  } else if (direction === "left") {
     this.xSpeed = -5;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
     this.xSpeed = 5;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  } else if (direction === "stop") {
     this.xSpeed = 0;
     this.ySpeed = 0;
  }
};

// Create the ball object
var ball = new Ball();
var object = new Object();
// An object to convert keycodes into action names
var keyActions = {
  32: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction);
});

// The animation function, called every 30 ms
setInterval(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ball.draw();
  ball.move();

  object.draw();

  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);

setInterval(function () {
  object.checkCollision();
}, 1)
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

How would you code this? Please give an example similar to mine.

Comment: first, urgent usually means you have a homework assignment due. second, you're asking us to do it for you. If you have specific questions about why something isn't working or how to get closer to your desired result, you might get more useful answers.

Comment: so what are you gonna do? talk about how i suck?

Comment: no. I'm going to explain that this isn't a good question, and nobody is going to just do it for you. what isn't working with your current code? what do you want to happen that isn't happening? What aren't you able to do yourself? Without that info, someone would have to start from scratch and write it for you completely. And like I said before, thats not how this works.

Comment: What is the difference between the code you have and what you are looking for? Where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like most of the functionality is there you're just missing the correct logic in the `checkCollision`. I would change it to something like:

```
Object.prototype.checkCollision = function() {
  var colx = (ball.x-ball.radius<this.x&&ball.x+ball.radius>this.x)||(ball.x-ball.radius<this.x+20&&ball.x+ball.radius>this.x+20);
  var coly = (ball.y-ball.radius<this.y&&ball.y+ball.radius>this.y)||(ball.y-ball.radius<this.y+20&&ball.y+ball.radius>this.y+20);

  if(colx&&coly){
    console.log('collision');
  }
}
```

`colx` checks the x collision, to see if the ball is in between the objects position. `coly` does the same thing but for the y variable. If both are true then there is a collision.

I added `radius` variable to `Ball`

```
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = width / 2;
  this.y = height / 2;
  this.xSpeed = 5;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.radius = 10;
};
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94ptvzfo/)

Comment: how would you make it stop? the xspeed and yspeed would be set to 0 right? but then it would automatically update again.

Comment: make the ball stop? Ignore input too?